# simple sql query containing 'in'-clause, checking for better syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, in-clause

I'm wondering about the best way to perform a SQL query.
I have a table which contains SUBJECTS which are related to ARTICLES (each article contains at least 2 SUBJECTS).
The user is searching for two SUBJECTS and I need to reply with all articles.

I have a table which looks like this:

> SubjectID  ---> key
>
> ArticleID

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT  ArticleID
FROM    tblSubjectsInArticles
WHERE   SubjectID = @pSubjectID1
        AND ArticleID IN (SELECT ArticleID FROM tblSubjectsInArticles WHERE SubjectID = @pSubjectID2);
```

I got a feeling that there is a better way to perform this task, maybe an efficient query or a different data structure. Maybe one of you guys know a better way or you can reassure that this is the best way. Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: In SQL Server chances are the query in your question is more efficient than the one in the answer you accepted. 

Additionally the one in that answer has different semantic in that it can bring back duplicates that you would then need to get rid of with `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct s1.ArticleID
from   tblSubjectsInArticles s1
         join tblSubjectsInArticles s2 
           on s1.ArticleID = s2.ArticleID
where  s1.SubjectID = @pSubjectID1
   and s2.SubjectID = @pSubjectID2
```

So you would create a joined table on the ArticleIDs and filter on the related subjects. The distinct makes sure your list contains only unique ArticleIDs

Comment: How the `SubjectID` could equal to two different values (because of the `AND`) in the same time with a `INNER JOIN`?